# Array repeats one value

Tags: c#, arrays, repeat, fill

I have filled an array of this object and I think I'm filling it fine until I ask to repeat what I have just filled it with and see that they are all the same result. I know it's something simple but I'm missing it right now.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numOFItems = 6;
    int population = 10;

    int[] geneList = new int[numOFItems];
    Genome[] gen = new Genome[population];
    Random rand = new Random();
    Genome gene;

    for (int i = 0; i < population; i++)
    {
        gen[i] = new Genome();
        for (int j = 0; j < numOFItems; j++)
        {
            geneList[j] = rand.Next(0, 4);
        }
        gene = new Genome(geneList);
        gen[i] = gene;
        Console.Out.Write("\n" + gen[i].ToString());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < population; i++)
        Console.Out.Write("\n" + gen[i].ToString() + ";");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

class Genome
{
    int[] geneList;
    int numOFItems = 6;

    public Genome()
    {
        geneList = new int[numOFItems];
    }

    public Genome(int[] geneList)
    {
        this.geneList = geneList;
    }

    public int[] GeneList
    {
        get { return geneList; }
        set { geneList = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "" + GeneList[0] + GeneList[1] + GeneList[2] 
            + GeneList[3] + GeneList[4] + GeneList[5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only initializing `geneList` once - so each `Genome` contains a reference to the same array. Move your declaration and initialization of `geneList` inside the loop. Note that you're *also* creating a new `Genome` instance right at the start of the list, and overwriting it afterwards. So I think your loop ought to look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < population; i++)
{
    int[] geneList = new int[numOFItems];
    for (int j = 0; j < numOFItems; j++)
    {
        geneList[j] = rand.Next(0, 4);
    }
    gen[i] = new Genome(geneList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps.. yeah i get that now. great

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration the reference gene is assigned a new Genome(geneList), then the reference gen[i] is assigned address of the object pointed to by gene. So on and so on, at the end you will always get all the objects to be the value of the last generated Genome(), because you keep overwriting the memory location pointed to by gene. Try to assign new Genome(geneList) directly to gen[i].

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of the geneList array so that it's inside the for-loop:

```
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            int numOFItems = 6;
            int population = 10;


            Genome[] gen = new Genome[population];

            Random rand = new Random ();

            for( int i = 0; i < population; i++ )
            {

                int[] geneList = new int[numOFItems];

                for( int j = 0; j < numOFItems; j++ )
                {
                    geneList[j] = rand.Next (0, 4);
                }


                gen[i] = new Genome (geneList);

                Console.Out.Write ("\n" + gen[i].ToString ());
            }
            for( int i = 0; i < population; i++ )
            {
                Console.Out.Write ("\n" + gen[i].ToString () + ";");
            }
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
```

(I've simplified your code a bit as well)

Otherwise, you only use one geneList-array, which you modifiy each time inside the loop, but every Genome instance uses the same geneList-array.  (That is, they all use the same reference to that array).